# Getting changes to upstream projects and including them in email

Tags: html, jenkins, build, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins job that has 4 upstream jobs.

What I want help with:

Include the changes to upstream jobs in the email which is sent after the build for the downstream Jenkins job is complete.

The email that I send is a html report, which is generated by my python script as a post-build action. I include the html report as a pre-send action written in groovy script.

Answer (score 0):

Does this plugin address your needs?
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BlameSubversion

**Edit:**
For non-plugin solution, you will have to extract the SCM log from the API. Take any build (not job) URL, and add `/api` to the end to get a list of possible options. You may try `/api/xml` to get all the information in XML format. The SCM commit messages are under `<changeSet>` element.

Comment: I am looking for a non plugin based solution. Something by using the Jenkins REST APIs. Thanks.